# Android maven plugin issue with MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, android, maven

I am trying to build android project with maven. I am experimenting with the configuration, but I cant figure out whats the source of problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.4.2:apk (default-apk) on project android: MojoExecutionException:
 ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "E:\android\Android_sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package -f -M D:\zxing2\zxing\android\target\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\zxing2\zxing\android\res --auto-add-overlay -A D:\zxing2\zxing\android\target\generated-sources\combined-assets -I E:\android\Android_sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar -F D:\zxing2\zxing\android\target\android-4.7.6.ap_ --debug-mode", Result = -1073741819 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is the path to plugin correctly referred in maven?

Comment: Path to android maven plugin? Its correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try bellow `<plugin>`:

```
<properties>
    <it-plugin.version>4.4.1</it-plugin.version>
</properties>


<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>

      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${it-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <sdk>
          <platform>19</platform>
        </sdk>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```